# 'tensorflow.contrib' has no attribute 'constrained_optimization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, github

`tf.__version__=1.8.0`

I installed the cpu version of Tensorflow by pip.
While trying to run the examplt provided by github for constrained_optimization,I got this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfco = tf.contrib.constrained_optimization



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-9c9704a9d654>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Anaconda3/envs/tf/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/constrained_optimization/untitled1.py', wdir='D:/Anaconda3/envs/tf/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/constrained_optimization')

  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Anaconda3/envs/tf/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/constrained_optimization/untitled1.py", line 12, in <module>
    tfco = tf.contrib.constrained_optimization

  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    return getattr(module, item)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib' has no attribute 'constrained_optimization'
```

I can't find the constrain_optimiztion folder in the tensorflow folder /contrib/ like what has been provided in github master.

```
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          all_reduce
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          android
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          batching
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          bayesflow
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          boosted_trees
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          cloud
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          cluster_resolver
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          coder
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          compiler
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          copy_graph
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          crf
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          cudnn_rnn
2018/07/01  17:34    <DIR>          data
```

While the github master offered :

```
tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/constrained_optimization/
```

Shall I try the GPU version? Or build tensorflow from github? Or Just copy the folder into my pip version?